# CakePHP 2.x Performance - Can I bring the View to the user before the Controller has finished working on the data?

Tags: performance, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a CakePHP 2.x app handling a tourism agency/operator's day-to-day sales and operations.

The Sales Model interacts with pretty much all other Models, because it needs client information from Clients, agent information from Agents, passenger information from Passengers (Not always the same thing as client), its payment information in Payments, tour info in Tours, flights info in Flights, etc.

Basically, when a sales staff person navigates to a specific sale, they need the screen to show them lots of information that come from other Models.

This has made the screen slower and slower to load.

I'm avoiding using cache, because this is a boots-on-the-ground type agency, meaning they're not just selling, they're actually doing the operations themselves. In this environment, information always needs to be the most up to date.

So, the question is:

Is there a way for me to bring the View to the user before the controller finishes handling every piece of data?

Like:

```
<?php

class SalesController extends AppController {

  public function show($id) {


    // Get easy/quick data
    // Take user to the View


    // Get the more time consuming data
    // Feed it to the View as it becomes ready


  }

}
```

I've been thinking I should just call the page with the simple data and then have the more complicated data come in after loading, with some Ajax and javascript, but is that the best use of the framework?

An average sale's screen takes about 10000 ms to fully load at this point. Over 6000 ms of that time is Idle frame. That means it's my Controller working in the background, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely not possible without breaking the "*controllers should never echo data*" rule, violating it can cause all sorts of problems, like the data not being returned in the test environment, headers not being sent, data not being read completely, etc.

If you know what you're doing, and you're aware about the implications, then you could probably get away with it, but the AJAX solution ist most likely the safer workaround.

In any case I wouldn't do anything before identifying *where exactly* and *why exactly* the time is spent, and figuring if there's a way to speed up things at the root of the problem!

Comment: I think I know where and why: Sales hold the package together. The package is basically all of the flights, all of the tours, all of the hotels, etc. Because these get saved to different Models, the data is not standard, so the Controller goes into each relevant record that was returned and does 2 tasks: 1. Pull out date and time so the final array can then be put into cronological order. 2. Pull out what would be considered descriptive in each type to create the description that is shown to the user.